# Can't open Google Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: google-chrome, 16.04

When ever I try to open Google Chrome from the terminal I get this. Any help?

```
mario@mario-Peppy:~$ google-chrome-stable

[0512/185023:ERROR:nss_util.cc(98)] Failed to create /home/mario/.pki/nssdb directory.
[0512/185023:ERROR:nss_util.cc(98)] Failed to create /home/mario/.pki/nssdb directory.
[19787:19821:0512/185024:ERROR:nss_util.cc(98)] Failed to create /home/mario/.pki/nssdb directory.
[19787:19821:0512/185024:ERROR:cache_util.cc(134)] Unable to move cache folder /home/mario/.config/google-chrome/ShaderCache/GPUCache to /home/mario/.config/google-chrome/ShaderCache/old_GPUCache_000
[19787:19821:0512/185024:ERROR:cache_creator.cc(129)] Unable to create cache
[19787:19821:0512/185024:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(589)] Shader Cache Creation failed: -2
[0512/185024:ERROR:nss_util.cc(98)] Failed to create /home/mario/.pki/nssdb directory.
[19787:19787:0512/185024:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(410)] readlink failed: Permission denied
[19787:19787:0512/185024:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(246)] readlink(/home/mario/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied
[19787:19787:0512/185024:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(246)] readlink(/home/mario/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied
[19787:19787:0512/185024:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(270)] Failed to create /home/mario/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock: Permission denied
[19787:19787:0512/185024:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(410)] readlink failed: Permission denied
[19787:19787:0512/185024:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(246)] readlink(/home/mario/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied
[19787:19787:0512/185024:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1379)] Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.
```

Comment: @bc2946088 Running chrome with `sudo` might get the browser running, but it's a very bad idea security-wise, and will only compound any permissions problems.

Comment: What are the permissions of your actual home directory? (`ls -ld /home/mario`)

Comment: Totally right, @NickWeinberg.  Initially I was thinking for just debugging but overlooked it would create all of those files with elevated permissions, which as you mentioned, would make things worse.  I've deleted the comment.

Answer (score -2):

I tried

```
sudo chown -Rc $USER:$USER $HOME
```

Reference: [Google Chrome can't launch in Mint 19 Cinnamon - Linux Mint Forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=284622)

Comment: You tried but was it successfull?

Comment: yes it worked for me